# How could I delete multiple collection with regex

Tags: mongodb

How could I delete multiple collection with regex

Suppose I have a bunch of collections

```
user_r1
user_milk_r3
user_cat_r4
...
```

How could I delete all the collection with name starting with **user**

So I can do it by the following command

> db[/user_*/].drop()

Answer (score 1):

You could first get all the collection names in the db using **[`getCollectionNames()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/)** method then **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** the array with the regex expression, iterate over the filtered list and drop:

```
var rgx = /user_*/,
    collections = db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(col){
        return col.match(rgx);
    });

collections.forEach(function(name){
    db.getCollection(name).drop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Console,

```
var rgx = /user*/,
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(name) {
    if(name.match(rgx)) { 
        db.getCollection(name).drop();
    }
  });
```